# Gridview Event Sorting is not handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GV in which I am data binding it manually. But the problem is that it is giving me this err:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   The GridView 'gvAgentList' fired event
>   Sorting which wasn't handled.

Same for the page indexing. Here is the function I wrote to do it from the code behind:

```
 protected void gvAgentList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedEntity; //string for Labeling in Master Page!
        int selectIdEntity; //int for storing Plan IDs in Plan Page!
        GridViewRow row = gvAgentList.SelectedRow;
        selectedEntity = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        selectIdEntity = Int16.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text.ToString());
        Session["EntityIdSelected"] = selectIdEntity;
        Session["EntitySelected"] = selectedEntity;
        Response.Redirect("~/FrontEnd/Users.aspx?EntityID=" + row.Cells[1].Text.ToString());
    }
```

I DONT know which event handler should I use here? Its not calling this function when I am doing a page index change! Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are manually doing the data binding, you have to handle all the events around it.

For sorting, you should have a handler for GridView's [`Sorting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) event (the msdn doc has a good example).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" />
```

and

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bala, what about the Indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the sorting event with JavaScript and you probably should remove the sort handling with the backend code. Also dont forget to remove AllowSorting=true all together.

I generally implement jquery datatables for front end handling such as sorting and what not. Here is a link to get you started: http://www.datatables.net/.